# Dedekind-finite rings

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$. We say that $R$ is **Dedekind-finite** if it satisfies the condition
\begin{align}
\forall a,b\in R(ab=1 \Longrightarrow ba=1).
\end{align}
Assume $R$ is a Dedekind-finite ring and $e\in R$ is a nonzero idempotent. Assume also that $R \cong eR$ as a right $R$-modules. How to prove that $e=1$ ?!.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi$: $eR\to R_R$ be the isomorphism. For some $a \in R$ we have $1 = \varphi(ea) = \varphi(e^2 a) = \varphi(e) ea$ (homomorphism) $= ea \varphi(e)$ (Dedekind finiteness) $\in eR$.

Why does $1 \in eR$ imply $e = 1$? If you multiply $ef = 1$ by $e$ from the left, the LHS does not change, while the RHS becomes $e$.

Comment: Well, $eR$ isn't supposedly proper, it's supposedly nonzero.  Indeed we *hope* $eR$ isn't proper so that we can show $e=1$.  You can still get there from $1=xea=eax$, because this indicates $e$ is right invertible.  The only right invertible idempotent is $1$ (easy exercise.)

Comment: That 'supposedly' on my part was regarding an unstated beginning of a proof by contradiction :-) And yes, '$1 \in eR$ implies $e = 1$' is absolutely necessary here.

Comment: You already have most of a non-contradiction proof, which is usually preferred, if it's easy!